# Not able to read my gmail inbox using the imap python module

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the code that is supposed to read my Gmail account.

```
import smtplib
import time
import imaplib
import email
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

ORG_EMAIL = '@gmail.com'
FROM_EMAIL = 'amitesh.sahay@gmail.com'
FROM_PWD = '<my_password>'
SMTP_SERVER = 'imap.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT = 993

# -------------------------------------------------
#
# Utility to read email from Gmail Using Python
#
# ------------------------------------------------


def read_email_from_gmail():
    try:
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
        mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
        mail.select('inbox')

        type1, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
        mail_ids = data[0]

        id_list = mail_ids.split()
        first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
        latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])

        for i in range(latest_email_id,first_email_id, -1):
            type1, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)' )

            for response_part in data:
                if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                    msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
                    email_subject = msg['subject']
                    email_from = msg['from']
                    print('From : ' + email_from + '\n')
                    print('Subject : ' + email_subject + '\n')

    except ValueError:
        print("Oops!  That was no valid mailbox.  Try again...")
```

When I execute the code, it runs without throwing any error, but it's not giving any output as well. I am using python 3.6 and Installed all the python package that comes inbuilt within PyCharm. Is there anything that somebody can point out which could be a probable issue?

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling your function. Your first step needs to be some very basic debugging -- put in some print statements to verify the function is being called, that variables have the values you expect, that loops are looping, etc.

Comment: Thank you, now I am getting other error, but I can get through it on my own.